# Select individual td of tables

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>        
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>        
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>        
  <td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Which outputs:

```
123
456
789
```

How can I select each `<td>` individually with `jQuery`? What selector is there?

Comment: Can we see the jQuery code you've tried?

Comment: Do you simply mean... `$('td')`?

Comment: Didn't try any since I don't know the particular selector.

Comment: Seriously? You tried *nothing* because...you didn't feel like doing any research? You realise that Stack Overflow is "[a site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)," right? If you can't be bothered to research, *why* should we spend our (free) time helping you?

Comment: I don't think that telling that I tried $('table').find('tr'); which finds all tr's would help that much when I'm searching for a more complex selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use special jQuery selectors:

// second row

```
$row2 = $('table').find('tr:eq(1)');
```

// Find 3rd element in 2nd row

```
$el3  = $row2.find('td:eq(2)');
```

// Then access the value with either `.text()` or `.html()`

```
$valueEl3 = $el3.text();
```

Indexes begin at 0.

Comment: Is there no other way than to insert the tr's into variables? I mean a single selector, like you would search in a double array, like array[2][1]?

Comment: You can always chain the methods `$('table').find('tr:eq(1)').find('td:eq(2)');`. You could also 'flat' select the td from all table tds : `$('table').find('td:eq(4)');` - this one would select `[2,2]` (if the table has 3 cols)

Comment: You could also simplify this by creating a function that does the heavy lifting for you: `function getCell(row, cell){ return $('table').find('tr:eq('+ row + ')').find('td:eq(' + cell + ')'); }` this would essentially let you call that entire double find jQuery selection with just `getCell(2,1)` and you can do any additional jQuery you want at that point like this for example `getCell(2,1).html("10");` -- @GeorgeIrimiciuc, this gives a nicely simplified syntax you were asking for above.

Comment: Yes I had this idea too, perhaps even extend jQuery, fn first check if element is table, the returns the value via the same code.

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/b3Pkn/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$.each($('table td'), function (index, value) {
    alert($(value).html());
});
```

Comment: This would iterate through the td's, what I'm looking for is individually selecting them.